# Is there something issue in indentation, while using Anaconda's Spyder

Tags: python, selenium, anaconda, spyder, indentation

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

This code snippet pops an error of indentation while running in Anaconda's Spyder. This the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Panch\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Panch\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 29, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver as RemoteWebDriver
  File "C:\Users\Panch\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .remote_connection import RemoteConnection
  File "C:\Users\Panch\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 34, in <module>
    from .errorhandler import ErrorCode
  File "C:\Users\Panch\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
                                                     ^
```

**IndentationError**: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Please let me know if anything I am missing out.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas Thanks for suggestion. I have edited the description with full trace error.

Comment: it is strange behavior. Maybe there is invisible char which makes problem. Do you have this problem when you run exactly this file directly in console/terminal/cmd.exe without `Spyder`? What if you create new file in Spyder and write code manually (without using copy-paste)?

Comment: There are no issues in executing in cmd.exe, however when I am trying to execute it from Anaconda Prompt window similar error pops up.

Comment: it would means that file and code is OK but problem has only anaconda and problem is in file `selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py`. Maybe if you reinstall module `selenium` in Anaconda then it will work correctly. Or you can open file `errorhandler.py` in text editor which has function `"convert tabs to spaces"` and use this fucntion and save it back to the same file.

Comment: Thanks a lot @furas. It actually worked, somehow the file errorhandler.py got some spaces for which this issue was raised.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204327/discussion-between-panch-mukesh-and-furas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is strange behavior but maybe somehow file `selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py` was broken.

You can open this file in text editor which has function `"convert tabs to spaces"`, use this function and save it back to the same file.

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

...implies that there are indentation issues with in the lines of code.

Apparently, I don't see any indentation issue with in the lines of code you have published. However, there is a possibility of <kbd>Space</kbd> characters mixed in with your <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

---

### Solution

There are different solutions as per the IDE you are using as follows:

- Try to search and replace all the tabs with a few spaces as [*Spaces*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) are the preferred method for [*indentation*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).
- In [sublimetext](/questions/tagged/sublimetext) you can **`set`** or **`unset`** by *checking* or *unchecking* to use tabs for indentation:

  ```
  View --> Indentation --> Convert Indentation to Tabs
  ```
- To fugure out the tabs/spaces issue you can use `tabnanny` as follows:

  ```
  python -m tabnanny your_python_file.py
  ```
- Within the Python editor, select all the code/text and do the following:

  ```
  Go to Format -> Untabify Region
  ```
- Incase you are using [vim](/questions/tagged/vim), press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and do the following to auto indent everything and will clear up any spaces you have .
- On [Atom](https://atom.io/), go to:

  ```
  Packages > Whitespace > Convert Spaces to Tabs
  ```