# unindent does not match any outer indentation level error when compiling the Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, indentation

Error:

```
unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Code:

```
def confirmation(self):
    if WebDriverWait(self.driver, 1000).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'failed'))):
        print("Checkout Failed!")

     if WebDriverWait(self.driver, 1000).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'succesful'))):
        print("Checkout Succesful!")
```

How can I address the error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492387/indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message...

```
unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

...implies that there is a problem with the indentation in your code block.

This error is mostly observed when there is a mixup of <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd> characters while indenting Python code.

---

### Analysis

When I copied you code block and executed:

[image: indentation_problem]

I got the same error:

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop\directory\PyPrograms>class_in_python.py
  File "C:\Users\Soma Bhattacharjee\Desktop\Debanjan\PyPrograms\class_in_python.py", line 26
    def confirmation(self):
              ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Once, I removed all the white paces and the new line character and break up the line again for the following line of code, the default indentation seems to be different:

```
     if WebDriverWait(self.driver, 1000).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'succesful'))):
        print("Checkout Succesful!")
```

[image: indentation_difference]

---

### Solution

You need to fix up the indentation of the following lines:

- `EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'failed'))):`
- `EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'succesful'))):`

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [Is there something issue in indentation, while using Anaconda's Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59351371/is-there-something-issue-in-indentation-while-using-anacondas-spyder/59352554#59352554)

Answer (score 0):

The indent of the 2nd 'if' does not match the first, it is in one extra space.  In python, your indentation must be consistent

Basically the places you *could* indent that 2nd 'if' would be even with the first 'if' or even with the first 'print' (in which case the 2nd 'if' would be within the first 'if').  The current location of the 2nd 'if' doesn't match any of these previous levels so python throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

You have a new line after `.until(` python is considering this a new line of code thus throwing the error. Also your second if and print have an extra space before them.

```
def confirmation(self):
    if WebDriverWait(self.driver, 1000).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'failed'))):
            print("Checkout Failed!")

    if WebDriverWait(self.driver, 1000).until(
      EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'succesful'))):
          print("Checkout Succesful!")
```